# How to filter a dataframe of dates by a particular month/day?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So my code is as follows:

```
df['Dates'][df['Dates'].index.month == 11]
```

I was doing a test to see if I could filter the months so it only shows November dates, but this did not work. It gives me the following error: AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'month'.

If I do

```
print type(df['Dates'][0])
```

then I get class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp', which leads me to believe that the types of objects stored in the dataframe are Timestamp objects. (I'm not sure where the 'Int64Index' is coming from... for the error before)

What I want to do is this: The dataframe column contains dates from the early 2000's to present in the following format: dd/mm/yyyy. I want to filter for dates only between November 15 and March 15, independent of the YEAR. What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks.

Here is df['Dates'] (with indices):

```
0    2006-01-01
1    2006-01-02
2    2006-01-03
3    2006-01-04
4    2006-01-05
5    2006-01-06
6    2006-01-07
7    2006-01-08
8    2006-01-09
9    2006-01-10
10   2006-01-11
11   2006-01-12
12   2006-01-13
13   2006-01-14
14   2006-01-15
...
```

Comment: Please show an example of what `df` looks like. You probably want to `df.set_index('Dates')`, but it's hard to say without seeing.

Comment: Edit your question with `df` so that it's formatted correctly. Post the head of the entire dataframe if you can.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Map an anonymous function to calculate the month on to the series and compare it to 11 for nov.
That will give you a boolean mask. You can then use that mask to filter your dataframe.

```
nov_mask = df['Dates'].map(lambda x: x.month) == 11
df[nov_mask]
```

I don't think there is straight forward way to filter the way you want ignoring the year so try this.

```
nov_mar_series = pd.Series(pd.date_range("2013-11-15", "2014-03-15"))
#create timestamp without year
nov_mar_no_year = nov_mar_series.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m-%d"))
#add a yearless timestamp to the dataframe
df["no_year"] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m-%d"))
no_year_mask = df['no_year'].isin(nov_mar_no_year)
df[no_year_mask]
```

Comment: The int64 was actually because accessed the index first with `df['Dates'].index.month`. In this case the index was an Int64Index which doesn't have a month attribute.

Answer (score 69):

#### Using `pd.to_datetime` & `dt` accessor

The accepted answer is not the "pandas" way to approach this problem.
To select only rows with `month 11`, use the `dt` accessor:

```
# df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) -- if column is not datetime yet
df = df[df['Date'].dt.month == 11]
```

Same works for days or years, where you can substitute `dt.month` with `dt.day` or `dt.year`

Besides that, there are many more, here are a few:

- `dt.quarter`
- `dt.week`
- `dt.weekday`
- `dt.day_name`
- `dt.is_month_end`
- `dt.is_month_start`
- `dt.is_year_end`
- `dt.is_year_start`

For a complete list see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#time-date-components)

Comment: This approach wouldnt work for old dates, e.g. `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1031-11-29 00:00:00`. For such data you **have** to use some magic

Answer (score 4):

In your code there are two issues. First, need to bring column reference after the filtering condition. Second, can either use ".month" with a column or index, but not both. One of the following should work:

```
df[df.index.month == 11]['Dates']

df[df['Dates'].month == 11]['Dates']
```