# How to filter specifc months from Pandas datetime index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a daily dataset which ranges from 2000-2010. I already set the column 'GregDate' via

```
df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['GregDate']))
```

as index. Now I only want to investigate the months from November till March (for all the ten years).

My dataframe looks like this:

```
                Sigma        Lat        Lon
GregDate                                   
2000-01-01  -5.874062  79.913437 -74.583125
2000-01-02  -6.794000  79.904000 -74.604000
2000-01-03  -5.826061  79.923939 -74.548485
2000-01-04  -5.702439  79.916829 -74.641707
...
2009-07-11 -10.727381  79.925952 -74.660714
2009-07-12 -10.648000  79.923667 -74.557333
2009-07-13 -11.123095  79.908810 -74.596190

[3482 rows x 3 columns]
```

I already had a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873772/how-to-filter-a-dataframe-of-dates-by-a-particular-month-day-python-pandas), but I still am not able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DatetimeIndex.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month.html) and [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df = df[df.index.month.isin([11,12,1,2,3])]
print (df)
               Sigma        Lat        Lon
GregDate                                  
2000-01-01 -5.874062  79.913437 -74.583125
2000-01-02 -6.794000  79.904000 -74.604000
2000-01-03 -5.826061  79.923939 -74.548485
2000-01-04 -5.702439  79.916829 -74.641707
```

Comment: I'm using Pandas version 0.19.2, and this was giving me an error that "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isin' ". df.index.month is a numpy array; I had to cast to a pandas series before this solution would work. Is this just a version change thing?

Comment: Was able to filter using `alldat['month']=alldat.index.month
alldat[alldat.month.isin([11,12,1,2,3])]`

Comment: @EHB if use old pandas try numpy  `df = df[np.in1d(df.index.month, [11,12,1,2,3])]
print (df)`, untested.

Answer (score 6):

```
In [10]: df.query("index.dt.month in [11,12,1,2,3]")
Out[10]:
               Sigma        Lat        Lon
GregDate
2000-01-01 -5.874062  79.913437 -74.583125
2000-01-02 -6.794000  79.904000 -74.604000
2000-01-03 -5.826061  79.923939 -74.548485
2000-01-04 -5.702439  79.916829 -74.641707
```