# pandas filter on DatetimeIndex by excluding date range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a `pandas.DataFrame` which has a `pandas.DatetimeIndex` and a set of values.

I would like to **exclude** all the dates in a given `pandas.date_range` from this `pandas.DataFrame`.

Example code:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='04/01/2012', end='04/01/2019', freq='MS')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[100]*len(dates),index=dates,columns=["val"])

exclusion_dates = pd.date_range(start='04/01/2012', end='04/01/2019', freq=pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=12))
```

**My attempt:**

```
df.loc[~exclusion_dates,:]
```

Ideally this would lead to `df` containing all dates **except** for `1st April YYYY`

However, this leads to the below error:

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'DatetimeIndex'

I looked at the below thread, however could not find anything:
[Filtering Pandas DataFrames on dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898824/filtering-pandas-dataframes-on-dates)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter specifc months from Pandas datetime index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352371/how-to-filter-specifc-months-from-pandas-datetime-index)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `isin()`:

```
df.loc[~df.index.isin(exclusion_dates)]

            val
2012-02-01  100
2012-03-01  100   <-- April excluded
2012-05-01  100
2012-06-01  100
2012-07-01  100
2012-08-01  100
2012-09-01  100
2012-10-01  100
2012-11-01  100
2012-12-01  100
2013-01-01  100
2013-02-01  100
2013-03-01  100   <-- April excluded
2013-05-01  100
...
```

Note: The default format treats your date strings as mm/dd/yyyy.  So use:

```
pd.date_range(start='04/01/2012', end='04/01/2019', ...)
```