# How can I filter this DataFrame by month?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a column that holds time values with a '%dd/%mm/YY %hh:%ss' format (e.g.: '31/12/2018 23:35'). I want to get a dataframe with only a determined month. 
[image of the DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7fCJ.png)

Comment: 1) I recommend changing your time column to `datetime` type with `df['time_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_column'])`; 2) then you can do, for example `df[df['time_column'].dt.month == 1]` for January.

Comment: See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59604826/9081267)

Answer (score 0):

you can filter an entire dataframe by columns value with something like

```
filtered_df = df.iloc[df["month"] == desired_cell_value]
```

Edit for OP's comment: Wants to know how to iterate through

```
date_col = "col_name"

df["mmyyyy"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df[date_col]).month + pd.DatetimeIndex(df[date_col]).year * 100

values = pd.unique(df[date_col].values)

for date in values:
    filtered_df = df.iloc[df["mmyyyy"] == date]
    #do your stuff
```

create a column that's Month/Year. Then you can create a list of month/years in the df and iterate through one by one.

Comment: Yes, but there are thousands of values and multiple days per month.

Comment: got you :) Will make a tweak to my post to help you with that

Comment: Just updated  @mszsorondo Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time... I´m not really understanding the last answer, I tried to suit it inside my program but it throws a new error every time I correct something.