# Filtering and manipulating datetime in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandasql

Okay, guys, I am wondering what's going. I have a pandas `dataframe` that I pulled from `MySQL`.

In fact here was my query syntax:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM mywebsite.com WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-12-01' AND '2020-03-31'"

websitedata = pd.read_sql(query,con=engine)
```

Then I `exported` the data as `CSV`. Now today `reading` from the `CSV` and trying to split the data in `chunks` of `dates`

```
Dec2019 = df.loc[(df.date >= "2019-12-01") & (df.date <= "2019-12-31")]
Jan2020 = df.loc[(df.date >= "2020-01-01") & (df.date <= "2020-01-31")]
Feb2020 = df.loc[(df.date >= "2020-02-01") & (df.date <= "2020-02-29")]
Mar2020 = df.loc[(df.date >= "2020-03-01") & (df.date <= "2020-03-31")]


len(df) == len(Dec2019) + len(Jan2020) + len(Feb2020) + len(Mar2020) # gives me False
```

Infact `len(Dec2019) + len(Jan2020) + len(Feb2020) + len(Mar2020)` gives `376440`

And `len(df)` gives `384274`

How can I do preview the frame to see what went wrong? Like December 2019, January 2020,..., March 2020 to understand the issue?

PS: the date is already a `pandas datetime` column

Comment: one way I would diagnose where I could be losing data points is inserting a 'year-month' column into the df
a) Parse the string to an actual datetime through strptime
b) then create a column combining df.date.year + '-' df.date.month 
c) draw a value_counts on the new year-month column

Comment: Is `date` a datetime or an actual string? What does `df['date'].dtype` show?

Comment: `Others = df.loc[(df.date < "2019-12-01") | (df.date > "2020-03-31")]`. Is it empty?

Comment: If the date is already a datetime then try: `df['date'].to_period('M').value_counts()`...

Comment: @JonClements I get `AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_period' `It is not set as the index but as a separate column

Comment: @PandasJ sorry... do `df['date'].dt.to_period('M').value_counts()`...

Comment: Yes it is a datetime. I did `df.date.to_period("M").value_counts()`

Comment: @JonClements I see apart from March, every other data is a little away from it. Could something be wrong with my expression? Is there an elegant way to reference a month?

Comment: nothing obvious from what you've pointed as to why... are you sure your query just genuinely isn't returning a different set of results than at the time you created your csv files or when you wrote your CSV files you hadn't done something that would make it different than the query results etc...?

Comment: @JonClements `df.loc[(df.date < "2019-12-01") | (df.date > "2020-03-31")]` gives `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the most efficient way to do this that gave me the exact frame without date leakages.

Using `datetime dt accessor`

```
Jan2020 = df[df.date.dt.month == 1]
Dec2019 = df[df.date.dt.month == 12]
Feb2020 = df[df.date.dt.month == 2]
Mar2020 = df[df.date.dt.month == 3]
```

Infact this now returns `True`

```
len(df) == len(Dec2019) + len(Jan2020) + len(Feb2020) + len(Mar2020)
```

Credit: [How to filter a dataframe of dates by a particular month/day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873772/how-to-filter-a-dataframe-of-dates-by-a-particular-month-day)