# Filter rows by column date values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I retrieve the information from a json file like this:

```
dataFile = pd.DataFrame(meta_json['data'])
```

The dataFile looks like this now:

```
calculation_date              value        time         person 
2020-02-28T09:40:57.636642    W725s        NaN          Nick
2020-02-28T09:40:59.292392    XTSKT        NaN          Leon
2020-03-09T12:33:05.814107    GSHDT        15:26        Felix
2020-03-15T12:33:06.292989    GSHXT        NaN          Oliver
2020-05-09T12:33:05.814107    SKJKD        NaN          Criss
```

How can I filter the rows by the month in the columns? So if I want march, it should filter just the rows from march. The day and time is not relevant in that case.
The result should look like this:

```
calculation_date              value        time         person 
2020-03-09T12:33:05.814107    GSHDT        15:26        Felix
2020-03-15T12:33:06.292989    GSHXT        NaN          Oliver
```

I have tried with:

```
dataFile['calculation_date'].str.contains("2020-03")
```

But it gives me only true and false values.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59604826/9081267)

Comment: `dataFile[dataFile['calculation_date'].str.contains("2020-03")]` if your `dataFile` column is a string