# filter data frame by specific dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the data frame below with dates ranging from 2016-01-01 to 2021-03-27

```
timestamp   close   circulating_supply  issuance_native
0   2016-01-01  0.944695    7.389026e+07    26070.31250
1   2016-01-02  0.931646    7.391764e+07    27383.90625
2   2016-01-03  0.962863    7.394532e+07    27675.78125
3   2016-01-04  0.944515    7.397274e+07    27420.62500
4   2016-01-05  0.950312    7.400058e+07    27839.21875
```

I'm looking to filter this dataframe by Month & Day to look at the circulating supply on December 31st for each year.

here is an output of the datatypes of the data frame

```
timestamp             datetime64[ns]
close                        float64
circulating_supply           float64
issuance_native              float64
dtype: object
```

I'm able to pull single rows using this:

```
ts = pd.to_datetime('2016-12-31')

df.loc[df['timestamp'] == td]
```

but no luck passing in a list of datetimes inside df.loc[]

The result should look like this, showing the rows for December 31st of each year:

```
timestamp   close   circulating_supply  issuance_native
0   2016-31-12  0.944695    7.389026e+07    26070.31250
1   2017-31-12  0.931646    7.391764e+07    27383.90625
2   2018-31-12  0.962863    7.394532e+07    27675.78125
3   2019-31-12  0.944515    7.397274e+07    27420.62500
4   2020-31-12  0.950312    7.400058e+07    27839.21875
```

This is the closest Ive gotten but I get this error

```
#query dataframe for the circulating supply at the end of the year
circulating_supply = df.query("timestamp == '2016-12-31' or timestamp =='2017-12-31' or timestamp =='2018-12-31' or timestamp =='2019-12-31' or timestamp =='2020-12-31' or timestamp =='2021-03-01'")
​
circulating_supply.drop(columns=['close', 'issuance_native'], inplace=True)
circulating_supply.copy()
circulating_supply.head()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4308: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  return super().drop(
```

Comment: please share the output of `df.dtypes`
to perform operations as datefield you will first need to change the type of the columns

Comment: done, see the main post for the edits. Thanks

Comment: when you say smallest dataframe from month and day, are you looking for the month-day combination that has the smallest number of records? Can there be more than one entry per day? can there be missing days? what does `pull a smaller data frame from this by month & day, specifically December 31st of each year.` mean?

Comment: Apologies, I clarified the original post as well. I'm essentially looking to query the data frame for the circulating supply values on a specific date (December 31st of each year in the data frame).

Comment: you can first seperate out month and date for each row and then filter based on those

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter a dataframe of dates by a particular month/day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873772/how-to-filter-a-dataframe-of-dates-by-a-particular-month-day)

Comment: Not quite as I need to filter on both Month and Day, that link says I can only do one or the other

Comment: What about `df[df.timestamp.isin(your_list)]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```py
end_of_year = [
    pd.to_datetime(ts)
    for ts in [
        "2016-12-31",
        "2017-12-31",
        "2018-12-31",
        "2019-12-31",
        "2020-12-31",
        "2021-03-01",
    ]
]
end_of_year_df = df.loc[df["timestamp"].isin(end_of_year), :]
circulating_supply = end_of_year_df.drop(columns=["close", "issuance_native"])
circulating_supply.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by ignoring the error I got when using the .drop() function on my df.query result

```
#query dataframe for the circulating supply at the end of the year
circulating_supply = df.query("timestamp == '2016-12-31' or timestamp =='2017-12-31' or timestamp =='2018-12-31' or timestamp =='2019-12-31' or timestamp =='2020-12-31' or timestamp =='2021-03-01'")

circulating_supply.drop(columns=['close', 'issuance_native'], inplace=True)
circulating_supply.copy() #not sure if this did anything
circulating_supply.head()

#add the column 
yearly_issuance['EOY Supply'] = circulating_supply['circulating_supply'].values

yearly_issuance.head()
```