# Python - How to export monthly data into excel based on month?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe that contain two columns. Date from 2018 until now and Orders with order count for each day.

```
Date    Orders
0   2018-01-01  57
1   2018-01-02  324
2   2018-01-03  54
3   2018-01-04  677
4   2018-01-05  234
5   2018-01-06  54
6   2018-01-07  234
7   2018-01-08  65
8   2018-01-09  234
9   2018-01-10  54
10  2018-01-11  234
11  2018-01-12  65
12  2018-01-13  7
13  2018-01-14  6
14  2018-01-15  57
15  2018-01-16  324
16  2018-01-17  54
17  2018-01-18  677
18  2018-01-19  234
19  2018-01-20  54
...
```

I need to export this into multiple excel files so that every files contain only data for one particular month.

I am trying to work on this script but i am struck:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("data/SampleData.xlsx")
for dates in Date:
    currMonth = something???
    filename = 'file_'+list(set(pd.to_datetime(df.loc[currMonth, 
    'datestart']).dt.strftime('%m%d%y')))[0]+'.xlsx'
    df.loc[idx, 'data'].to_excel(filename)
```

So I think i have to create variable that will store start and end of each month and than iterate through it.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59604826/12661819). You can use simple integers to address the month, so you should be able to iterate like this (not tested):

```
for month in range(1, 13):
    df_per_month = df[df['Date'].dt.month == month]
    df_per_month.to_excel(f'{month}.xlsx')
```

Edit: Note that according to [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html), `month` ranges from 1-12.

Also, if you want to iterate month *and* year, you would have to do something like:

```
for year in range(2018, 2022):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        data = df[(df['Date'].dt.month == month) & (df['Date'].dt.year == year)]
        data.to_excel(f'{month}-{year}.xlsx')
```